# Inserting a specific row multiple times in VBA

Tags: vba, insert, row

Our clients want their excel sheets formatted to where a new header (The entire '1' row) to be inserted above the last value whenever a new value in column 'A' is present

Essentially I am copying row '1' and inserting it whenever I find a new value in column 'A'

Here is the sub I am using to format it, but it just keeps looping and crashes.

```
Sub insertHeader()

Range("A2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) Then

        ActiveCell.Offset.Select

    Else

        Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        ActiveCell.Offset.Select

    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: what have you tried to find the error? Does this Loop should move from row to row until a cell is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell Offset how and where to offset. As in Offset(row offset, column offset):

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select
```

Oh, and also your copy, man... Ok, here is the code:

```
range("a3").select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

  If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then 
  'comparing it upwards, as the standard insert will insert a row above your active cell.

    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
    Range("a1").EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     'move on to the row I was at before inserting a new row

  End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

Comment: Awesome Possum. Man, can't believe I missed that offset and my logic was flawed. Thank you so much.